# How Much Time before Closing a Question?

Tags: discussion, moderation

Sometimes, the community can help the questioner clarify/elaborate the question, or make it on-topic by changing it appropriately.

In such cases, closing too soon---specially, by mods, and before any democratic process---does not help (no offence!). I think if there is a **convention** (not a rule!), such as "mods will not close a question in the first 5 hours," will be of help.

Comment: I'm the guilty party here, on http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/1633/are-there-any-resources-for-atms-automated-teller-systems-based-on-real-time-sy , but it seemed like there was absolutely no hope of fixing the question. Apologies for jumping the gun and breaking the process.

Comment: And plus, we do have a convention: http://meta.cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/299/on-closing-and-the-awesome-power-of-moderation - I just broke it :(

Comment: @Suresh: In any case, I don't accuse you of any guilt. Quite contrary, your very decent moderation (as well as Ryan's) keeps this site up and running in a great manner. I was just **suggesting** to allot some time, maybe we (the community) can help the questioner fix the problem. And, thanks for pointing me to the convention.